# Call another app route from different app route in Flask

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I have one webapp flask that running to handle the data charting to display and some gpio control. all the function such as displaying data from SQLite db, and gpio control from button totally work.

this code below is my webapp flask that contain many app-route. my main problem is:

1. when I press button for turn off/on the relay, somehow my data wont load automatically. so I must hit refresh button manually
2. when I type the specific number for input, and expect the data displayed as the range on specific number it will work if I did this before I hit gpio control button for relay. but I hit the gpio control button, I'm unable to do this and the web page said "method not allowed".

so on my point of view, it may work if we add some code to call the index rout ("/") inside this route: `@app.route("/<changePin>/<action>")`, but unfortunately, I have little experience with python and flask, on PHP webserver might work but don't know with this type of language. maybe you can give me some clue?

my goals is, the page will able to handle both action which is controlling gpio (relay), and displaying data with chart with matplotlib

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import io
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
#import water

from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file, make_response, request
app = Flask(__name__)

import sqlite3


#GPIO NEEDS############################################################
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
# Create a dictionary called pins to store the pin number, name, and pin state:
pins = {
   13 : {'name' : 'Waterpump 1', 'state' : GPIO.LOW},
   19 : {'name' : 'Growlight 2', 'state' : GPIO.LOW}
   }

# Set each pin as an output and make it low:
for pin in pins:
   GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
   GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)

conn=sqlite3.connect('../sensorsData.db')
curs=conn.cursor()


# Retrieve LAST data from database
def getLastData():
    for row in curs.execute("SELECT * FROM DHT_data ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"):
        time = str(row[0])
        temp = row[1]
        hum = row[2]
    #conn.close()
    return time, temp, hum


def getHistData (numSamples):
    curs.execute("SELECT * FROM DHT_data ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT "+str(numSamples))
    data = curs.fetchall()
    dates = []
    temps = []
    hums = []
    for row in reversed(data):
        dates.append(row[0])
        temps.append(row[1])
        hums.append(row[2])
    return dates, temps, hums

def maxRowsTable():
    for row in curs.execute("select COUNT(temp) from  DHT_data"):
        maxNumberRows=row[0]
    return maxNumberRows

#initialize global variables
global numSamples
numSamples = maxRowsTable()
if (numSamples > 101):
    numSamples = 100
    
    
# main route 
@app.route("/")
def index():

    
    time, temp, hum = getLastData()
    templateData = {
      'time'        : time,
      'temp'        : temp,
      'hum'         : hum,
      'numSamples'  : numSamples,
      'pins' : pins
#      'text' : text
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)

#method for gpio########################################################
def main():
   # For each pin, read the pin state and store it in the pins dictionary:
   for pin in pins:
      pins[pin]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin)
   # Put the pin dictionary into the template data dictionary:
   templateData = {
      'pins' : pins
      }
   # Pass the template data into the template main.html and return it to the user
   return render_template('index.html', **templateData)



@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    global numSamples 
    numSamples = int (request.form['numSamples'])
    numMaxSamples = maxRowsTable()
    if (numSamples > numMaxSamples):
        numSamples = (numMaxSamples-1)
    
    time, temp, hum = getLastData()
    
    templateData = {
      'time'        : time,
      'temp'        : temp,
      'hum'         : hum,
      'numSamples'  : numSamples
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
    
    
@app.route('/plot/temp')
def plot_temp():
    times, temps, hums = getHistData(numSamples)
    ys = temps
    fig = Figure()
    axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    axis.set_title("Temperature [C]")
    axis.set_xlabel("Samples")
    axis.grid(True)
    xs = range(numSamples)
    axis.plot(xs, ys)
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    output = io.BytesIO()
    canvas.print_png(output)
    response = make_response(output.getvalue())
    response.mimetype = 'image/png'
    return response

@app.route('/plot/hum')
def plot_hum():
    times, temps, hums = getHistData(numSamples)
    ys = hums
    fig = Figure()
    axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    axis.set_title("Humidity [%]")
    axis.set_xlabel("Samples")
    axis.grid(True)
    xs = range(numSamples)
    axis.plot(xs, ys)
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    output = io.BytesIO()
    canvas.print_png(output)
    response = make_response(output.getvalue())
    response.mimetype = 'image/png'
    return response


###APPROUTEGPIO##########################################################
@app.route("/<changePin>/<action>")
def action(changePin, action):
   # Convert the pin from the URL into an integer:
   changePin = int(changePin)
   # Get the device name for the pin being changed:
   deviceName = pins[changePin]['name']
   # If the action part of the URL is "on," execute the code indented below:
   if action == "on":
      # Set the pin high:
      GPIO.output(changePin, GPIO.HIGH)
      # Save the status message to be passed into the template:
      message = "Turned " + deviceName + " on."
   if action == "off":
      GPIO.output(changePin, GPIO.LOW)
      message = "Turned " + deviceName + " off."

   # For each pin, read the pin state and store it in the pins dictionary:
   for pin in pins:
      pins[pin]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin)

   # Along with the pin dictionary, put the message into the template data dictionary:
   templateData = {
      'pins' : pins
   }

   return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
##approutesoil################################################################
#@app.route("/sensor")
#def action():
#    status = water.get_status()
#    message = ""
#    if (status == 1):
#        message = "Water me please!"
#    else:
#        message = "I'm a happy plant"
#
#    templateData = template(text = message)
#    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)



if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=False)
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you to use the same route for different controller functions. In your case it is `/` route.

Comment: i've been doing some research, and many says using jquery / jquery's ajax lib. i dont have any experience using jquery and doesnt know how its work. would you mind to suggest me some sort of page for learning this ?